# Is there a hole in the Galilean group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_cohomology#Motivation)

> If ${\displaystyle G}$ is a compact simply connected Lie group, then
>   it is determined by its Lie algebra, so it should be possible to
>   calculate its cohomology from the Lie algebra.

So, if  [Galilean group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_group#Galilean_group) were compact and simply connected, then it would have one two-dimensional hole inside because [the second cohomology group of the Galilei algebra is one-dimensional](https://books.google.hu/books?id=H0iZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=%22If+G+is+the+Galilean+group+then%22&source=bl&ots=onqgBX0R9Y&sig=ACfU3U2LdTVBaEnIfOPwdL3TUAB2qT5eiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGw-6vrPrkAhWSqIsKHVRtC_cQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22If%20G%20is%20the%20Galilean%20group%20then%22&f=false), and because the dimension of the $k$-th cohomology group means the number of the $k$-dimensional holes in $G$ as topological space.

But, unfortunately, the Galilean group isn't compact, so I'm not sure that the cohomology of its Lie-algebra reflects its homology. But perhaps yes. So, my question is that how this group looks like. Is there a hole inside, or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every connected Lie group $G$ has a [maximal compact subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup) $K$ to which it is [homotopy equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence); in particular $G$ and $K$ have the same cohomology (with any coefficients). The maximal compact subgroup of the Galilean group is the subgroup $SO(3)$ of rotations. Topologically this is [real projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_space) $\mathbb{RP}^3$, whose real (and even rational) cohomology is the same as that of the $3$-sphere $S^3$: we have $H^0 \cong H^3 \cong \mathbb{R}$ and all other real cohomology vanishes.

Hence, if you like, there is a "3-dimensional hole." But IMO one shouldn't take this hole idea too seriously as a description of cohomology.

Comment: Doesn't this contradict with [Guillemin-Sternberg](https://books.google.hu/books?id=H0iZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA191&lpg=PA191&dq=%22If+G+is+the+Galilean+group+then%22&source=bl&ots=onqgBX0R9Y&sig=ACfU3U2LdTVBaEnIfOPwdL3TUAB2qT5eiw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGw-6vrPrkAhWSqIsKHVRtC_cQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22If%20G%20is%20the%20Galilean%20group%20then%22&f=false)?

Comment: No. As you suspected, for noncompact Lie groups the Lie algebra cohomology doesn't necessarily tell you the cohomology of the group. For example, the Lie algebra cohomology of an abelian Lie algebra $\mathfrak{a}$ is $\Lambda^{\bullet}(\mathfrak{a}^{\ast})$ but the cohomology of the corresponding noncompact simply connected Lie group (which is $\mathfrak{a}$ again) is trivial (except in degree zero).

Comment: Here's being talked of algebra- and group cohomology, but does this always coincide with a cohomology obtained from just a topological object like the real projective space?

Comment: @Nikolaj: for a topological group $G$ it's a bit ambiguous what "cohomology of this group" means. One could mean its cohomology as a topological space, or one could mean its "group cohomology," whatever that means, which is the cohomology of some version of the classifying space $BG$.

Comment: It's a surprising fact about compact simply connected Lie groups that their cohomology, as a topological space, can be recovered from the cohomology of their Lie algebras, as Lie algebras.